Migrate local users to Active Directory domain without data loss
So I've been looking for a solution to properly migrate local users to an Active Directory domain, I tried using ForensIT tool (profwiz) it helps migrating all files and documents but not the applications data (All accounts will be logged off and all browsers cookies will be lost), I don't want applications to lose their state.
I've tried copying my local user AppData to the AD account it keeps browsers history and websites marked as favorite but all saved password & cookies are gone.
Thanks in advance.
